# SocialEngine PHP classes in application/libraries are not being loaded

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm developing a web application based on SocialEnginePHP 4.10.

I've added a library to /application/libraries by following these steps:
- Developer SDK -> Create a Package (choosing type = Library)
- Added the library .tar skeleton via Package Manager -> Install New Package (all good and successful)
- I added the files containing the PHP classes of the library inside /application/Libraries
- tried to instantiate one of the classes from within a different module but I got this error:

```
    2018-03-19T22:40:58+00:00 ERR (3): Error Code: 4247ae
Error: Class 'CamShowAPI' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/social-engine-4.10.1/application/modules/Livecams/controllers/CamshowController.php:9

Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/social-engine-4.10.1/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): Livecams_CamshowController->webserviceAction()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/social-engine-4.10.1/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('webserviceActio...')
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/social-engine-4.10.1/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/social-engine-4.10.1/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(84): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/social-engine-4.10.1/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/social-engine-4.10.1/application/index.php(223): Engine_Application->run()
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/social-engine-4.10.1/index.php(25): include('/Applications/M...')
#7 {main}
```

Just in case, I then tried to:
- Developer SDK -> Build Package 
- delete the library
- add again the library using the newly built package so that all the files would be mentioned inside application/packages/library-camshow-4.0.0.json

Got the same error.
What am I doing wrong? How do I tell SE to load my Libraries' classes?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Module`, not a `Library`. Developers are adding new features with modules. API classes such as `CamShowAPI` mentioned can go to Api folder of the new module.

Comment: I solved the namespace problem but thank you very much for coming back to me. There are reasons for keeping the library separated from the module that uses it, but I'd be very interested in knowing more about the prupose of the /Api folder that is included in every module if you have this kind of info...